# Is there any way to delay in showing full number pagination in data table

Tags: jquery, sql-server, datatables

I am using server side pagination in jquery-datatable.

I have two sql queries

1. Query will fetch the record with offset, limit (pagination needs). (Takes X seconds to execute)
2. to retrieve total count without Limit (Takes Y seconds to execute, taking significant amount of time as first query)

As I have thousands of records to show it takes (X+Y) seconds to execute the query and then render the data table.

I want to save time by showing datatable first without pagination and  a separate ajax call will be made to retrieve the total count after datatable renders and show pagination.

Thus, I can save Y seconds in showing datatable. Please assist how can I achieve the same.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: I have given general idea, i can't disclose the code as per NDA. I will try to create sample datatable, it will take time. If you can think of any configuration or any way to delay load total count and pagination

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a single query to return the data and total rowcount?  What back-end/db are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008, returning total count will result in total_count in every row. 

 select* from (
  select 
  row_number() over (order by emp_id) as rowNo
  , count(1) over () as total_count 
  from T_EMP
  where emp_id='987545' )e where rowNo BETWEEN 1 and 100 

here count(1) over() is also a little costly it executes for each row. UI performance perspective i want to show the user data table as early as possible